"Operation not permitted" when trying to compile code in Databricks
I am trying to compile my code in Databricks using the following code:
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "setup.py", "bdist_wheel"], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

print("Standard Output:\n", stdout.decode())
print("Standard Error:\n", stderr.decode()) 

However, I am facing an error please see the logs below:
stdout: running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
copying idp_databricks/init.py -> build/lib/idp_databricks
stderr: error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
I have tried moving the files to compile to within my workspace as well as requesting the admin to try running this. But still facing the same error.
What permission is missing in order to successfully run?

I can't reproduce the error. What happens if you run python setup.py bdist_wheel from the terminal?

@Iqram Choudhury I have posted the solution Please check if it's working for you?

When you are using shared cluster, this error comes due to permission constraint in shared cluster.
But the recommended ways of installing or importing custom modules is given in this documentation
In your case either add the workspace files to sys path like below.
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))

or build a .whl  file and install it in cluster libraries.


Correct, I am using a shared cluster, this has worked previously for me on a no isolation shared cluster. My goal is trying to compile my code in my ntbks to a .whl file in a unity catalog location. This is the part of the compilation code it fails with the permission issue.

I have given how to use  .whl files in databricls. Please check it. Compiling in shared cluster is not recommended that's the reason you are facing the error. Since it effects the same to users using that cluster
